# Fetch Facebook user ID not yet users of my app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Is it possible to get userId of upcoming users of my app? I need to add upfront permission to users, who not yet started using my app, but when they would first use it the already need to see some data.

Or shall I check their name?

Comment: You will only get their app-scoped user id, when they log in to your app for the first time. _“Or shall I check their name?”_ - if it doesn’t need to be secure at all, maybe … anyone could change their name on Facebook to anything. Email might be a bit more reliable, at least that’s been verified by Facebook - but then you might exclude users who only signed up using their mobile, and do not have an email on file with Facebook.